# Correcting the spacing of a phrase using PHP

Tags: php

Consider This string that has wrong spacing:

```
$q1 = '   little  cute girl';
```

(3 at the beginning, it should be no space)
(2 between 'little' and 'cute', it should be 1)

If I explode and print_r,

```
$r1 = explode(' ', $q1);
print_r($r1);
```

The output will be:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => little [4] => [5] => cute [6] => girl )
```

What can I do so that $q1 can be properly spaced,

```
$q1_after_correction = 'little cute girl'
```

so that after explode and print_r, the output to be like this: (No space at beginning!)

```
Array ( [0] => little [1] => cute [2] => girl )
```

Any idea please?

Comment: See the linked question to remove repeated spaces and use `trim()` to remove leading and trailing ones.

Comment: Just modify your `$r1` like this `$r1 = array_values(array_filter(explode(' ', $q1)));`

Comment: @WahyuKristianto I tried  yours, it works!! No need regex!

Comment: Yep.. I'm just bored to answer in the answer column 

Comment: Oh u should, I'll accept your answer. I hate those regex answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$q1 = '   little  cute girl';
$spaceCleanUp = preg_replace('/\s/', ' ', $q1); // This will replace successive spaces with one
$r1 = explode(' ', $spaceCleanUp);
print_r($r1);
```